# Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string

Tags: python, string

> Return the number of times that the string `"code"` appears anywhere in
>   the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the `'d'`, so
>   `"cope"` and `"cooe"` count.

I have achieved this with the following code using regular expressions:

```
import re


def count_code(str):
    exp = '^co[a-z|A-Z]e$'
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(str) - 1):
        if re.match(exp, str[i:i + 4]):
            count = count + 1

    return count

print count_code('aaacodebbb')  # prints 1
print count_code('codexxcode')  # prints 2
print count_code('cozexxcope')  # prints 2
```

Is there any other way of achieving this without using regular expressions?

Comment: Your regex variant is inefficient. Have a look at [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re.findall#re.findall), and combine it with [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=len#len).

Comment: *"Is there any other way..."* - yes, of course there is. Do you have a real question?

Comment: `len(re.findall(r'co[a-zA-Z]e', string))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is you can make every possible string with co*e where * is any alphabet

Like

```
x=["co"+i+"e" for i in string.lowercase]
```

Then iterate

```
for i in x:
    if i in <your string>:
        count+=<your string>.count(i)
```

Comment: What if it's `codexxxcode`? That will only get one.

Comment: You could use str.count() to  count all instances of non-overlapping occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def count_code(str):
    x=["co"+i+"e" for i in str.lower()]
    count = 0
    index = 0
    for i in x:
        if i in str[index:]:
            index = str.find(i)+1
            count+=1
    return count

print count_code('aaacodebbb')  # prints 1
print count_code('codexxcode')  # prints 2
print count_code('cozexxcope')  # prints 2
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple and clean solution for this problem:

```
  def count_code(str):
      count = 0
      for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i:i+2] == "co" and str[i+3:i+4] == "e":
          count+=1
      return count
```

Comment: `str` is a python keyword.  Much simpler syntax would be to use "in".

Comment: Yes, I know that. The reason why I used word str is because this is a CodingBat exercise where they use str as a argument. But still it is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

To improve on other answers, notice that there is no need for slices. We can just compare the three positions of interest to the letters that should be there:

```
def count_code(str):
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(str)-3):
    if str[i]=='c' and str[i+1] == 'o' and str[i+3]=='e':
      count+=1
  return count
```

Comment: Please explain why this should be used over existing answers. Also, when submitting code, please make sure the code will actually compile first.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_code(str):
  a = 0
  for i in range(len(str) - 3):
    if str[i:i+2] + str[i+3] == 'coe':
      a += 1
  return a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also :
using Python String Method 'count'

```
 def count_code1(str):
       counts=0
       for i in range(97,123):   #all the lowercase ASCII characters
        count+= str.count('co'+chr(i)+'e')
       return counts
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_code(str):
  code = 0
  for c in range(len(str)-1):
    if str[c+1] == 'o' and str[c:c+4:3] == 'ce':
      code+=1
  return code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_code(s):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[-(i+3):-(i+1)]=='co' and s[-i]=='e':
      count=count+1
  return count
```

Comment: Avoid shadowing builtin type `str` with paramater named `str`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could define your logic in a way you can reuse like so - in this case without a count or regex

```
def count_code(str):
    start = 'co' #first 2 letter
    start1 = 'e' #last letter
    counter = 0 #initiate counter
    strlen=len(str) #for each word
    for i,x in enumerate(str):
        if str[i:i+2]==start: 
        #for each letter - is that letter and the next equal to start
            if len(str[i:strlen]) >=4: #is string long enough?
                if str[i+3]==start1: # if so is last letter right?
                    counter+=1
                else:
                    counter
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
def count_code(str):
  counter = 0
  for i in range(len(str)-3):
    if str[i:i+2] == 'co' and str[i+3] == 'e':
      counter +=1
  return counter
```

Hope can help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_code(str):
  a=''
  count=0
  for char in ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
    a=char
    count+=str.count("co"+a+"e")
  return (count)
```

Comment: Don't use `str` as a name, it's a builtin type and relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  a = 0
  for i in range(len(str)-3):
     if str[i:i+2] == 'co' and str[i+3] == 'e':
       a +=1
  return a
```

Comment: The same solution has already been given in previous answers.